# Update a variable without refresh in PHP

Tags: php, variables, auto-update

I need to update a variable named `$count` (in the below code) automatically. When my database update, `$count` be update immediately because i need to use value of `$count` in android app so i can't refresh `count.php` file every time.

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("","","");
mysql_select_db("u607509006_bd1",$con);

$query = "select * from content where status='a'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $count;
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Your can use jquery or ajax to send the data to a separate update page but that won't update the count on the current page.

Comment: Can't you just use an ajax request. The ajax request can return a value and you update your page as well. I'm not too sure about Android development, but can easily give you a solution in HTML + JS/ Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a [Jquery Ajax Request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on the client side like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "path/to/code/file.php" // change this to your path to your code
}).done(function(data) {
  // This is executed after the ajax request is complete
  // data should be the updated value. You can also return other data // types e.g. JOSN
  $('#counter').text(data);
});
```

JS Fiddle Example: https://jsfiddle.net/anik786/nvkdLhv2/2/